# Magento 1.7 stuck on billing information

Tags: magento-1.7

I try to checkout from my website but it remains on billing information tab. What is wrong?

http://www.caviarofswitzerlandshop.com/

Thanks

Comment: it might be a problem with function attracta_loadjs(url){...} or function attracta_shouldrun() {....} etc.

Comment: How do I remove that? Its not in magento modules ro uninstall

Comment: it seems some module with those function was causing the problem, is that right?

Comment: Seems, the problem is sorted out for the asker.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily debug this by looking at the requests (ajax requests) with Firebug (or Chrome Dev Tools):

[image]

As you can see you get more than the json expected by Magento... The "awesome" module that has to do something with Attracta adds some js tracking... to that ajax request...

Disable that module and it will work.

Comment: Module is not in magento to be disabled...how do I remove it?

Comment: `grep -R "Attracta" app` and see what you get...

Comment: where do I do that?

Comment: Log in on your server via SSH and run the command in your document root

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome Dev Tools (press F12 in Chrome) `network` tab to see what the ajax call is returning.

When I submit my billing info It only returns a lot of Javascript from an extension named `Attracta` in your shipping html. This breaks the markup of the returned JSON string.

My best guess is that this extension would be a nice place to start debugging. Please turn it off and see if the checkout works after that.

Comment: It is not a module. It is something offered by hostgator. I removed it but not luck yet. Could you guys please check again?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still there, please use Firebug or Dev tools as discribed above to check this. Might be caching?

Comment: do you know where this might be? I mean if its not a module where does it come from?

Comment: Did you turn off the module via app/etc/modules/Attracta.....xml ? if so, try clearing caching and rerun the compiler. If that doesn't work you might have a serious issue. Contact hostgator

Comment: I cant find the attracta moduke in app\etc\modules...

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Hostgator and let them help you with debugging

Comment: Hostgator just ruined my site and I had to restore it. They know nothing of the problem. Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this similar thing happen, and it was caused from php-mcrypt not being installed. Please check your php install to verify that it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving checkout.xml file from app/design/frontend/YOUR THEME/layout catalog. That will force magento to use checkout.xml file from base theme. Alternatively setup your magento theme back to default and see if it works. I had similar problem with one page checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the same thing, only in Magento 1.8. It turns out that I had an echo call in index.php (used for debugging, not in there by default), and it was appended to JSON file and corrupted the request. I removed it, and it worked as expected.